# `UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for `transfrom'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make some buttons for a "shop window" in my game. I cannot see where I went wrong in the code, but I get this error:

```
Assets/shopHandler.cs(34,17): error CS1061: Type
`UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for
`transfrom' and no extension method `transfrom' of type
`UnityEngine.GameObject' could be found. Are you missing an assembly
reference?
```

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class shopHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Item
    {
        public string name;
        public Sprite icon;
        public float price;
        public float dps;
        public int acquired;
    }


    public Item[] shopItems;

    public GameObject button;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        foreach (Item i in shopItems)
        {
            GameObject btn = (GameObject)Instantiate(button);
            ItemScript scp = btn.GetComponent<ItemScript>();

            scp.name.text = i.name;
            scp.price.text = "Price: $" + i.price.ToString("F1");
            scp.acquired.text = i.acquired.ToString();
            scp.dps.text = "$/s: " + i.dps.ToString("F1");
            scp.icon.sprite = i.icon;

            btn.transfrom.SetParent(this.transform);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because its "transform", not "transfrom". A little typo in your last line inside your start method.

Comment: Don't answer questions with a simple typo unless there are other issues in the code you wish to correct. This should have been a comment. Simply close as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"

Comment: @Programmer, I dont think he had the Privilege to comment, he's under 50 score...

Comment: @S.Fragkos True but that doesn't make it ok.